# Combining for loop with .each() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display json data in a table when a query is sent. The request works fine and everything gets displayed nicely. BUT:
jquery throws an TypeError: a is undefined when I try to display the content.

The content is getting displayed correctly the first time the page is loaded, but then refuses to update when another request is sent over the form. I simply want to append table rows to a table within the HTML:

```
<table id="table"></table>
```

the JS looks like this:

```
            for (var id = 0; id < 150; id++) {
                showItems(id);
            }

            function showItems(){
                $.each(json.list.item[id], function(i, val) {
                    var $r = $('<tr>');
                    var $c = $('<td>').text(i).appendTo($r);
                    $c = $('<td>').text(val).appendTo($r);
                    $("#table").append($r);
                });
            }
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the id passed on from the for loop to the each function, but I don't know how to fix this. Since JS doesn't have block scope within the for loop, the id variable should be accessible within the $.each() right? 
But I can't work out why jquery throws me the "a is undefined" error and the script won't react until the page is reloaded.I think it could be something with an undefined variable returning Null, but I don't know which.

Couldn't figure out the solution from reading tons of answers here and on the web (also about JS variable scope and closures).

http://jshint.com/ doesn't show any undefined variables except the jquery $S.

Help is greatly appreciated :)

**Edit:**
The _id fix didn't help. Here is the whole js code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#term").focus(function() {

    var full = $("#table > tbody > tr").length? true : false;
    if(full == false) {
        $("#message").empty();
        $("#table").empty();
    }
});

var getFood = function(){

    var food = $('#term').val();

    if(food ==''){

        $('#message').html("Ha! We haven't seen you type, so no request! Type something!<hr>");
    } else {

        $('#message').html("Your information is on its way!<hr>");

        $.getJSON("APICALL", function(json){
            console.log(json);

            for (var id = 0; id < 150; id++) {
                showItems(id);
            }

            function showItems(){

                $.each(json.list.item[id], function(i, val) {
                    var $r = $('<tr>');
                    var $c = $('<td>').text(i).appendTo($r);
                    $c = $('<td>').text(val).appendTo($r);
                    $("#table").append($r);
                });
            }

        });
    }
};

$('#search').click(getFood);
});
```

When I leave out the for loop but instead just use:

```
                $.each(json.list.item[0], function(i, val) {
                    var $r = $('<tr>');
                    var $c = $('<td>').text(i).appendTo($r);
                    $c = $('<td>').text(val).appendTo($r);
                    $("#table").append($r);
                });
```

To display only the first object it works fine and no error is thrown. That made me think it had something to do with the for/.each() connection.

**Edit2: Solution**

Applied the code proposed by @MM-tac in the form below and works perfectly:

```
        $.each(json.list.item, function (key, data) {
            console.log(key)
            $.each(data, function(index, data) {
                var $r = $('<tr>');
                var $c = $('<td>').text(index).appendTo($r);
                $c = $('<td>').text(data).appendTo($r);
                $("#table").append($r);
            });
        });
```

Comment: May need to add more code. What line is erroring? 'a' isn't even used in that code block, so I don't think that's where the error is.

Comment: try with `function showItems(_id)` and `json.list.item[_id]`

Comment: We need to guess the JSON structure, probably you don't access the data in the right way. Is it of the form `{ "list" : {  "item": [ "Text0", "Text1", ... ] }, ... }` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the structure. `{ "list": { "item : [ { "Offset" : 0, "Group" : "xx", "Name" : "y"} ]}`

Comment: Well, as @slash197 pointed out, you are not passing id to showItems() so it currently has nothing to loop on.

Comment: @Drazisil The loop works so far. I'm passing the showItems() the id variable in the for-loop. I'm really new to all this, I don't quite understand what you are suggesting to fix. Can you specifiy a little more please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use different [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for each object this way:

```
$.each(json, function (key, data) {
    console.log(key)
    $.each(data, function (index, data) {
        console.log('index', data)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What are your inputs?  Currently you're passing 'id' into your function 'showItems' (which doesn't actually have an input parameter).

Walking through your code, you have a for-loop calling your function 150 times, with a different index each time.  But this is inherently the purpose of each.  How is json.list.item constructed?  If it's nested, and you're looping through an array of arrays this could work (although the way it's written is a little unclear at first).

Also, you do not need to assign anything to $c, because those commands are doing an append action immediately.

If you give me some insight into your inputs I'll probably be able to help you more.

Comment: I input a json: `{
    "list": {
        "item": [
            {
                "offset": 0,
                "group": "X",
                "name": "X",
                "no": "X"
            },...`
And want to display all the elements (max.150) that come with the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (var id = 0; id < 150; id++) {
            showItems(id);
        }

        function showItems(id){
            $.each(json.list.item[id], function(i, val) {
                var $r = $('<tr>');
                var $c = $('<td>').text(i).appendTo($r);
                $c = $('<td>').text(val).appendTo($r);
                $("#table").append($r);
            });
        }
```

If you add `function showItems(id)` instead of `function showItems()` your `each()` will actually have something to loop on.

Comment: inserted the id within the `showItems(id) {....} ` but didn't change anything with the code error unfortunately. It works in the same way as before without the id.

Comment: I think we are getting crossed in translation. The code as you currently have it posted won't work, because within `showItems()` it doesn't know what `id` is. You need to replace `function showItems() {` with `function showItems(id) {` Here is the full corrected code, hopefully that will explain what I'm saying better if you compare? http://jsfiddle.net/9261rdgL/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! It might be wrong without the id. But at the moment it does work! (for whatever reason I don't now). Inserted the id, but this doesn't change the result I'm getting from the script.

Comment: Then I'm afraid without you posting the line number that throws the error (your debugging tools in any major browser will provide that) and what is on that line and above and below it, we've reached the limits of what I can help with. Good luck. :)

Comment: I think I'm trying to understand the JSON access a bit more with the code provided from mm-tac that seems to be the "proper" solution. Thanks for helping out and improving my learning @Drazisil

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem with this code:

```
            $.each(json.list.item, function (key, data) {
                console.log(key)
                $.each(data, function(index, data) {
                    var $r = $('<tr>');
                    var $c = $('<td>').text(index).appendTo($r);
                    $c = $('<td>').text(data).appendTo($r);
                    $("#table").append($r);
                });
            });
```

Thanks for everyone helping me. Greatly appreciated. The Stackoverflow community really is amazing.